# A general solution to continuity equation

Tags: differential-equations

Let us write the standard continuity equation $$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{\jmath} = 0.$$

Should the relation $\vec{\jmath} = \rho \vec{v}$ be considered as a general solution of the continuity equation? If so, how to derive it?

Comment: $\vec j=\rho \vec v$ is not a solution of the continuity equation, it is a parametrization of the variables present in it. With just this continuity equation, you can't get any solution because you have 1 (scalar) equation and 4 indepent variables.

Comment: Generally one *numerically* solves this problem. If you have strict boundary conditions and initial conditions, it may be possible to analytically solve for $\rho$.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of... The general solution of the wave equation in 1D is of the form $f(x \pm ct)$, with $f$ arbitrary.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solutions of the continuity equation are discussed in a paper C.F.Clement in *Series A, Mathematical and Physical Sciences*, Vol. **364**, No. 1716 (Dec. 12, 1978), pp. 107-119 ([link to pdf](http://yly-mac.gps.caltech.edu/z_temp/4%20soozen/zjunk/print%201%20copy%20/Clement1978%20copy.pdf))

Comment: Maybe you could discuss some of the relevant results?  Links aren't really fit as answers.