# Solving continuity equation under specific conditions

Tags: electromagnetism, fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws

I have been thinking about how to get a general solution for the continuity equation:

$$\frac{\partial \rho(\vec{r},t)}{\partial t}+\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{J}(\vec{r},t)=F(\vec{r},t)$$

and I figured the way to proceed is to reduce the problem to one I already know how to solve. Therefore, under the condition that the current density can be expressed as the gradient of some scalar function $V(\vec{r},t)$ (mathematically, $\vec{J}=\vec{\nabla}V$), we would get a laplacian operator in the continuity equation and end up with a Poisson's equation, which we can solve:

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\nabla^2V=F$$

and regrouping all the terms except for the laplacian:

$$\nabla^2V=G(\vec{r},t)$$

Of course, this solution proposal assumes that $\rho,F$ are known, which can be quite restricting, let alone that we already assumed before that $\vec{J}$ can be expressed as the gradient of a scalar function. Would it be of any interest for me to keep exploring this proposal or is it too restrictive from the beginning? Also, is there a general solution for the continuity equation?

Note: I've already checked [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111221/) but it doesn't really apply to my question, and the only answer there is to it has a negative score

Comment: Surely if $\rho, F$ are not known, then no method could solve the equation? I don't see that assumption as being restrictive. If you are in a uniform electric field in an isotropic medium, then $J = \sigma E$ is also uniform and would have zero curl. So in that case J could be represented as the gradient of a scalar function. (In conclusion, I think you're proposal is good in that it has the potential to describe real world systems)